# Openshift PHP include Fails

Tags: php, openshift, php-include, openshift-php-cartidges

I have an Openshift account set up with PHP 5.4.

I have two files that reside in the same directory:

> index.php
> LoginWebInterface.php

I have in my index.php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
...
include 'LoginWebInterface.php';
```

I get an error when visiting index.php that states:

> Warning: include(LoginWebInterface.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/lib/openshift/55181c105973ca076e000074/app-root/runtime/repo/index.php on line 55 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'LoginWebInterface.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/var/lib/openshift/55181c105973ca076e000074/app-root/runtime/repo/lib:/var/lib/openshift/55181c105973ca076e000074/app-root/runtime/repo/libs:/var/lib/openshift/55181c105973ca076e000074/app-root/runtime/repo/libraries:/var/lib/openshift/55181c105973ca076e000074/app-root/runtime/repo/src:/var/lib/openshift/55181c105973ca076e000074/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor:/var/lib/openshift/55181c105973ca076e000074/app-root/runtime/repo/vendors:/var/lib/openshift/55181c105973ca076e000074/php/phplib/pear/pear/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/lib/openshift/55181c105973ca076e000074/app-root/runtime/repo/index.php on line 55

I have read through the documentation/data on the following sites and attempted their solutions to no avail:

- https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-repository-layout.html
- https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html
- **[Sorry, not enough rep to make the rest links]**
- forums.openshift.com/cant-include-any-files-in-php-deployment
- stackoverflow.com/questions/23299277/php-require-once-fatal-error-in-openshift-maybe-a-filepath-issue-but-im-stump
- forums.openshift.com/cant-include-any-files-in-php-deployment
- forums.openshift.com/problems-with-path-of-openshiftinc-cakephp
- stackoverflow.com/questions/21075003/openshift-php-file-not-found-same-syntax-in-localhost

The solutions I have tried include:

- moving anotherCode.php into a folder titled lib in the same directory as index.php and using 'lib/LoginWebInterface.php'
- using $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR'] . '/app-root/runtime/repo/LoginWebInterface.php'
- using $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] . 'LoginWebInterface.php'
- using multiple levels of nested directory(__FILE__) . 'LoginWebInterface.php'
- many variations of one or more of the above

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. `include(__DIR__ . '/LoginWebInterface.php');`
2. `include('./LoginWebInterface.php');`
3. Check file permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I tried solution 1 and 2 and no luck. I'm going to check out the permissions as that seems to be the underlying issue...well...I'm hoping it is at least.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that you have added the included file into your git repository and done a "git push"?  You might also want to ssh into your application and make sure that you see that file there in the same directory as the index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, rather embarrassingly, that it was a user error on my part.

I originally got the error for a file and assumed there was something wrong with the folder structure. It turns out I simply had not created the file yet and once I did, I started getting include errors for other files.

Here's where I really should have paid attention: I hadn't created the other files either. I continued to troubleshoot files that really didn't exist because I was no longer paying attention to what the error was telling me.

Sooo, Lesson learned. READ all error messages and THINK about what they are telling me.

Thank you all for your help and time!